# D3.js tick format: show when month changes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using D3 (v4) to display a bar chart with dates on the x-axis.

I'm trying to get the ticks to display the day of the month, unless it's the 1st where I want it to display the month i.e. to indicate when the month changes. I don't even know where to start on this.

The current format looks like this:

[image]

But I want it to look more like this:

[image]

The current code that generates the axis is as follows:

```
let timeFormat = "%b %d"
xAxis = g => g
      .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height - margin.bottom})`)
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat(timeFormat)))
```

I basically need something along the lines of

```
let timeFormat = "%d == 0" ? "%b" :  "%d"
```

**I know this is nonsense JS in this context, but it illustrates the logic I'm looking for**

Here's a snippet with a simplified version of my chart:

```js
let keys = [];

var w = 400;
var h = 200;

var margin = {
  top: 30,
  bottom: 40,
  left: 50,
  right: 20,
}

var width = w - margin.left - margin.right
var height = h - margin.top - margin.bottom


var data = [
   {
      "count":100,
      "date":"2018-11-30T00:00:00"
   },
   {

      "count":50,
      "date":"2018-12-01T00:00:00"
   },
   {

      "count":75,
      "date":"2018-12-02T00:00:00"
   },
]


var x = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return new Date(d.date) }))
  .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.count)])
  .range([height, 0]);

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
  .attr('class', 'chart')
  .attr('width', w)
  .attr('height', h);

var chart = svg.append('g')
  .classed('graph', true)
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');
 
let timeFormat = "%b %d"
  
chart.append('g')
  .classed('x axis', true)
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
    .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat(timeFormat))
    .ticks(2)
  )

chart.append('g')
  .classed('y axis', true)
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Maybe your issue is that the first date is not `0`, is `1`

Comment: And you can't check like that, `%d` and `%b` are placeholders, maybe you need to check if the `let timeFormat = d3.timeFormat("%d") == "01" ? "%b" : "%d"` .

Comment: @oma What do you mean, 'the first date'? And I know I can't check like that, I said in my question that this was just to illustrate the logic behind what I'm asking.

Comment: can you check the line from my second comment ? it is working ?

Comment: No it's not working, it just displays the day. That's because it's simply declaring a string, so it can't change it's value as it's not repeatedly called for each tick. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Ok, I got it, and if you check this inside the `xAxis` function ? something like this ?

`xAxis = g => g
      .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height - margin.bottom})`)
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat(d3.timeFormat("%d") == "01" ? "%b" : "%d")))`

Comment: It's still just displaying the day, and never the month.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the `ticks` from the `scale` and use that to see if the previous tick was another month, and choose your format based on that:

```
const longFormat = d3.timeFormat('%b');
const shortFormat = d3.timeFormat('%d');
const axis = d3.axisBottom(x);
axis.tickFormat((d, i) => {
    const ticks = axis.scale().ticks();

    if (i > 0 && ticks[i - 1].getMonth() === d.getMonth()) {
        return shortFormat(d);
    }
    else {
        return longFormat(d);
    }
});

xAxis = g => g
    .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height - margin.bottom})`)
    .call(axis)
```

Edit: If you're not using time scale but rather `scaleBand`, you should be able to use the domain to calculate the format:

```
const ticks = axis.scale().domain();
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the kind of thing I'm looking for. I'm now getting the error 'd3.axisBottom(...).scale(...).ticks is not a function'. Could this be an issue with the D3 version (I'm using v4)?

Comment: Oh, probably. I'm using this code as well, but I'm on v5. Will se if I can see if I had it before bumping to 5.

Comment: @Charlie Could you create a snippet here or a jsFiddle for your code so that I can try it?

Comment: I've added a snippet to the question

Comment: Aaaannnd I've just noticed your method works for the snippet, guess I specified the wrong version of D3

Comment: @Charlie You mean "works" as in works for you or for the snippet?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185075/discussion-between-charlie-and-jle).

Answer (score 0):

another version:

```
    function multiFormat(date) {
      var formatMillisecond = d3.timeFormat(".%L"),
        formatSecond = d3.timeFormat(":%S"),
        formatMinute = d3.timeFormat("%I:%M"),
        formatHour = d3.timeFormat("%I %p"),
        formatDay = d3.timeFormat("%_d"),
        formatWeek = d3.timeFormat("%_d"),
        formatMonth = d3.timeFormat("%b"),
        formatYear = d3.timeFormat("%Y");
      return (d3.timeSecond(date) < date ? formatMillisecond
          : d3.timeMinute(date) < date ? formatSecond
          : d3.timeHour(date) < date ? formatMinute
          : d3.timeDay(date) < date ? formatHour
          : d3.timeMonth(date) < date ? (d3.timeWeek(date) < date ? formatDay : formatWeek)
          : d3.timeYear(date) < date ? formatMonth
          : formatYear)(date);
    }
...
.tickFormat(function(d){return multiFormat(d);})
...
```

```js
let keys = [];

var w = 400;
var h = 200;

var margin = {
  top: 30,
  bottom: 40,
  left: 50,
  right: 20,
}

var width = w - margin.left - margin.right
var height = h - margin.top - margin.bottom


var data = [
   {
      "count":100,
      "date":"2018-11-30T00:00:00"
   },
   {

      "count":50,
      "date":"2018-12-01T00:00:00"
   },
   {

      "count":75,
      "date":"2018-12-02T00:00:00"
   },
]


var x = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return new Date(d.date) }))
  .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.count)])
  .range([height, 0]);

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
  .attr('class', 'chart')
  .attr('width', w)
  .attr('height', h);

var chart = svg.append('g')
  .classed('graph', true)
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

function multiFormat(date) {
  var formatMillisecond = d3.timeFormat(".%L"),
    formatSecond = d3.timeFormat(":%S"),
    formatMinute = d3.timeFormat("%I:%M"),
    formatHour = d3.timeFormat("%I %p"),
    formatDay = d3.timeFormat("%_d"),
    formatWeek = d3.timeFormat("%_d"),
    formatMonth = d3.timeFormat("%b"),
    formatYear = d3.timeFormat("%Y");
  return (d3.timeSecond(date) < date ? formatMillisecond
      : d3.timeMinute(date) < date ? formatSecond
      : d3.timeHour(date) < date ? formatMinute
      : d3.timeDay(date) < date ? formatHour
      : d3.timeMonth(date) < date ? (d3.timeWeek(date) < date ? formatDay : formatWeek)
      : d3.timeYear(date) < date ? formatMonth
      : formatYear)(date);
}


  
chart.append('g')
  .classed('x axis', true)
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
    .tickFormat(function(d){return multiFormat(d);})
    .ticks(2)
  )

chart.append('g')
  .classed('y axis', true)
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```